# Save xml file for gtk2 with glade 3.14

Tags: gtk, glade

I'm trying to follow [a tutorial](http://projects.haskell.org/gtk2hs/docs/tutorial/glade/) about Gtk2Hs.
I stumbled about the problem described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294311/cant-use-a-glade-xml-file-with-haskell). I'm now trying to create a gtkbuilder xml file to use with gtk2 and load it similar to the description linked in the question. The resulting file I have now starts like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
  <!-- interface-requires gtk+ 3.0 -->
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="Hello Gtk2hs">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkBox" id="box1">
        ...
```

It looks almost fine. It starts with `<interface>` instead of `<glade-interface>` but there is still that line that says `<!-- interface-requires gtk+ 3.0 -->` and i still get the same error when running it.

How can I force glade to generate gtkbuilder files for gtk2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21628493/2211273) says that glade newer that version 3.8 just doesn't support gtk2. So you need to either wait for gtk3 support in gtk2hs or switch to glade-3.8.